# Rotating Rows and columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hi i have been trying to figure out how to rotate my rows and columns.I tried using the transpose but it didnt work. My dataframe looks like this

```
Country | Rates 2015 | Rates2016 | Rates2017 | GDP 2015| GDP 2016 | GDP2017
 World  |    6       |    7      |    8      |   2355  |  1235    |  324325
```

Isit possible to change to

```
        | Rates | GDP
 2015   |   6   |   2355
 2016   |   7   |   1235
 2017   |   8   |   34132
```

Yeah this is what im trying to do basically

Comment: Transpose `df.T`

Comment: first Explain your problem a little bit

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the transposed part is in the index. I can only assume that if you have tried `df.T` that you have not set the index correctly

```
In [185]: df.set_index('Country Name').T
Out[185]:
Country Name        A               B               C
2000                       5               2               2
2005                       3               1               2
2010                       1               5               6
2015                       7               2               9
```

If you want to name the index then you will also need to do

```
In [187]: df = df.set_index('Country Name').T

In [188]: df.index = df.index.rename('Year')

In [189]: df
Out[189]:
Country Name        A               B               C
Year
2000                       5               2               2
2005                       3               1               2
2010                       1               5               6
2015                       7               2               9
```

Comment: Added as answer since the OP suggested they tried transposing unsuccessfully in an edit